# Делаю "float: left" и картинка выходит за границу страницы

Tags: html, css

Делаю "float: left" для картинки и она после этого выходит за границу страницы... Такое впечатление, что страница перестала "чувствовать" высоту картинки.

Как грамотно разрешить ситуацию?

Comment: `float` выводит элемент из нормального потока, так-что возможны всяческие спецэффекты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте после картинки поставить

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Или задать `clear:both` и `content:' '` для псевдоэлемента after (`.floated-element:after {clear:both`; `content:' '}`)

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/VwFG7/ - **overflow: hidden**

http://jsfiddle.net/bJt9C/ - `<div class="clear"></div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/JBWyG/ - **clear: left**

http://jsfiddle.net/tvC9n/ - **:after**

Answer (score 0):

Алилуя!У меня помогло вставкой перед параграфом с картинкой. Ситуация - картинка заключена в параграф несколько штук подряд, задавал для текста расплываться, а картинке позволять себя обтекать справа. Со всем остальными было всё отлично, а проблемный параграф с картинкой вёл себя не как нужно с теми же параметрами, вместо прилипания к правому краю, съезжала в середину, теперь всё ок! [image: скриншот]